# Web services login page in PHP

Tags: php, json

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET"){
// Get post data`
$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) : "";
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']) : "";
//$status = 1; 

// Here we set by default status In-active.
// Save data into database
//$resultarray = array();
$query = "select admin_user , admin_password from doc_admin where admin_user  = '".$username."' and admin_password = '".$password."'";
$insert = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

            if (mysql_num_rows($insert)>0)
            {
                while ($rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($insert))
                    {
                    $outp .= '{"id":"'  . $rs["id"] . '",';
                    $outp .= '"admin_user":"'   . $rs["admin_user"]. '",' ;
                    $outp .= '"admin_password":"'   . base64_encode($rs["admin_password"]). '",' ;
                    $outp .= '"admin_status":"'   . $rs["admin_status"]        . '",';
                    $outp .= '"admin_data":"'   . $rs["admin_data"]        . '",';
                    $outp .= '"admin_calender":"'   . $rs["admin_calender"]        . '",';
                    $outp .= '"admin_suggestion":"'   . $rs["admin_suggestion"]        . '",';
                    $outp .= '"admin_agenda":"'. $rs["admin_agenda"]     . '"}'; 
                        // array_push($resultarray,$result);
                    }
            }

 }
mysql_close($conn);
/* JSON Response */
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($outp);
```

I want to show data of logged in person but it showing null value, but if it get null value in database it showing result in JSON format.

Comment: It's ridiculous to try process POST data in (REQUEST_METHOD == GET) condition block.

Comment: For future reference on this old question, it is worth knowing that passwords should never be stored in plaintext. They should be hashed using a strong hash and a per-user salt. PHP has functions to do this easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET"){
// Get post data`
$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) : "";
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']) : "";
//$status = 1; 

// Here we set by default status In-active.
// Save data into database
//$resultarray = array();
$query = "select * from doc_admin where admin_user  = '".$username."' and admin_password = '".$password."'";
$insert = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

            if (mysql_num_rows($insert)>0)
            {
                $rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($insert);
                $outp = json_encode($rs);
            } else {
                $outp = json_encode(array());
            }

 }
mysql_close($conn);
/* JSON Response */
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($outp);
?>
```

Comment: if database have null row it shows this null row. if not it show null array like "[]".